# array 1D para Bitmap

Tags: array, processamento-de-imagens, bitmap, c++-cli

Venho trabalhando em um projeto com FPGA que envia um array (1D) de Bytes de uma imagem em escala de cinza para o PC. Bem, elaborei um código simples com uma imagem qualquer para simular o envio e recebimento de um array e o erro permaneceu:

```
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    Bitmap ^bmpGray = gcnew Bitmap("C:\\users\\riacho\\pictures\\TestGray.jpg");         
    BitmapData^ bmGrayData = bmpGray->LockBits( Rectangle(0,0,bmpGray->Width,bmpGray->Height), ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, bmpGray->PixelFormat );

    array<Byte> ^arrayBmpGray = gcnew array<Byte>(bmpGray->Width * bmpGray->Height);

    Marshal::Copy( bmGrayData->Scan0, arrayBmpGray, 0, arrayBmpGray->Length);

    Bitmap ^bmpNewGray = gcnew Bitmap(bmpGray->Width, bmpGray->Height, PixelFormat::Format8bppIndexed);
    BitmapData^ bmpNewGrayData = bmpNewGray->LockBits(Rectangle(0,0,bmpGray->Width, bmpGray->Height), ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, PixelFormat::Format8bppIndexed );

    Marshal::Copy(arrayBmpGray, 0, bmpNewGrayData->Scan0, arrayBmpGray->Length);

    bmpGray->UnlockBits(bmGrayData);
    bmpNewGray->UnlockBits(bmpNewGrayData);

    pictureBox1->Image = bmpGray;
    pictureBox2->Image = bmpNewGray;
}
```

Saída 1:

[image: Saída]

Depois de vasculhar muito, percebi que trocando o `PixelFormat::Format8bppIndexed` para `PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb`, ou seja, tratando o código e o formato como uma imagem colorida o problema foi solucionado:

```
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    Bitmap ^bmpGray = gcnew Bitmap("C:\\users\\riacho\\pictures\\TestGray.jpg");         
    BitmapData^ bmGrayData = bmpGray->LockBits( Rectangle(0,0,bmpGray->Width,bmpGray->Height), ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, bmpGray->PixelFormat );

    array<Byte> ^arrayBmpGray = gcnew array<Byte>(bmpGray->Width * bmpGray->Height);

    Marshal::Copy( bmGrayData->Scan0, arrayBmpGray, 0, arrayBmpGray->Length);

    array<Byte> ^arraybmpGrayCpy = gcnew array<Byte>(bmpGray->Width * bmpGray->Height * 3);

    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 3; i<arraybmpGrayCpy->Length; i += 3)
    {
     arraybmpGrayCpy[i-1] = arrayBmpGray[c];
     arraybmpGrayCpy[i-2] = arrayBmpGray[c];
     arraybmpGrayCpy[i-3] = arrayBmpGray[c];
     c++;
    }

    Bitmap ^bmpNewGray = gcnew Bitmap(bmpGray->Width, bmpGray->Height, PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData^ bmpNewGrayData = bmpNewGray->LockBits(Rectangle(0,0,bmpGray->Width, bmpGray->Height), ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb );

    Marshal::Copy(arraybmpGrayCpy, 0, bmpNewGrayData->Scan0, arraybmpGrayCpy->Length);

    bmpGray->UnlockBits(bmGrayData);
    bmpNewGray->UnlockBits(bmpNewGrayData);

    pictureBox1->Image = bmpGray;
    pictureBox2->Image = bmpNewGray;
}
```

Sou novato em programação e gostaria de saber para o primeiro código o que está faltando, deve haver alguma propriedade que desconheço, pois o segundo código esta parecendo uma "gambiarra" porque há uma adaptação para funcionar.

Comment: Que linguagem de programação é? Coloque a tag da linguagem na pergunta, que assim isso ajuda à comunidade encontrá-la. :)

Comment: Outra coisa, indexado não deixa de ser colorido (ao menos em outras linguagens/ambientes). A diferença é que vc usa uma escala própria para mapeamento das cores. RGB, por outro lado, já é o mapeamento "comum" (geralmente com valores de 0 a 255 para cada uma das três bandas). Não conheço *absolutamente nada* de FPGA, mas se vc vai usar indexado, talvez faltou vc definir [a tabela de indexação](http://teodacor12d.blogspot.com.br/2011/02/indexacao-de-cor.html) (as vezes também chamada de *palette*).

Comment: Mais informações (em inglês): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color

Comment: A linguagem é c++/cli e uso o visual studio, tentei colocar na tag a linguagem de programação, porém é a primeira vez que posto algo e por critérios do site só acima de 300 pontos para permitir a tag: c++/cli. Agradeço muito a ajuda, vou pesquisar.

Comment: Por nada. Eu adicionei a tag. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou a tabela de indexação (*palette*), o problema foi resolvido adicionando o código:

```
ColorPalette ^palette = bmpNewGray->Palette;
array<Color> ^entries = palette->Entries;
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    entries[i] = Color::FromArgb(i,i,i);
bmpNewGray->Palette = palette;
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]